# Connection refused elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, rhel7

Trying to do a "curl http://localhost:9200" but getting "Failed connection refused" Firewalld is off and elasticsearch.yml file settings are set to default. Below is a portion of the yml file.

```
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/data/elasticsearch
#

# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
```

Below is a tail of the elasticsearch.log file:

```
[2018-03-29T07:06:02,094][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [TBin_UP] zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined), reason: new_master {TBin_UP}{TBin_UPRQ3mPvlpCkCeZcw}{-F76gFi0T2aqmf9MYJXt9A}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}
[2018-03-29T07:06:02,105][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [TBin_UP] new_master {TBin_UP}{TBin_UPRQ3mPvlpCkCeZcw}{-F76gFi0T2aqmf9MYJXt9A}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: apply cluster state (from master [master {TBin_UP}{TBin_UPRQ3mPvlpCkCeZcw}{-F76gFi0T2aqmf9MYJXt9A}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300} committed version [1] source [zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)]])
[2018-03-29T07:06:02,148][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [TBin_UP] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2018-03-29T07:06:02,155][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [TBin_UP] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2018-03-29T07:06:02,155][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TBin_UP] started
[2018-03-29T07:06:02,445][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [TBin_UP] [gc][14] overhead, spent [300ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2018-03-29T07:14:50,259][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TBin_UP] stopping ...
[2018-03-29T07:14:50,598][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TBin_UP] stopped
[2018-03-29T07:14:50,598][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TBin_UP] closing ...
[2018-03-29T07:14:50,620][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [TBin_UP] closed
```

Service status:

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-03-29 08:05:46 EDT; 2min 38s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 22384 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22384 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,668 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,669 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,669 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,670 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logger config "root"
Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,671 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_indexing_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "index.indexing.slowlog.index"
Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,671 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_search_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "index.search.slowlog"
Mar 29 08:05:36 satyr elasticsearch[22384]: 2018-03-29 08:05:36,672 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "deprecation_rolling" for logger config "org.elasticsearch.deprecation"
Mar 29 08:05:46 satyr systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 29 08:05:46 satyr systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Mar 29 08:05:46 satyr systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

Comment: could you post the output of sudo service elasticsearch status?

Comment: Check whether the elasticsearch is running.

Comment: sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service shows active and running after doing a start but then shows failed shortly afterwards.

Comment: I added the failed message.

Comment: I did a rpm -i .... when installing. Is there an easy way to uninstall and simply reinstall.